# Can anyone identify this sword, believe to be Ottoman Empire (Turkish)?

Tags: weapons, identification

I am trying to identify a sword believe to be Ottoman Empire (Turkish).

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look at some of the other ["identification"](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) questions - usually people will ask for multiple pictures including some out of the sheath, closeups of any identifying markings and whatever provenance you have.  May also be worth explicitly stating what you want to know; otherwise people will reply, "Yes, that is a sword."

Answer (score 7):

I think it's this one:

[image]

This is an Ottoman shamshir with a sabre blade (common shamshirs have more curved blades). It's from the late 19th century. If there is an engraving in the blade, it will tell you the precise origin.

The "metallic" parts in the hilt and the scabbard should be an inlaying of silver. I think silver can be polished even if it's so badly damaged as yours.

Comment: the symbol at the top of the scabbard is different. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @GlennAhlstrand They are the same, the flag of the Ottoman Empire (called "Star and Crescent"). Your star is a bit bigger, that is why an inscription in the blade would give us more details. The Shamshir in my photo is actually Bulgarian from 1876, yours is probably pure Turkish (to use modern names) and a bit later.

Answer (score 3):

Looks similar to a [shamshir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamshir) but many examples of those have straight quillions.  Photo of blade would be helpful.

An example of a Shamshir

[image: An example of a Shamshir]

Comment: OP's photo doesn't seem to have nearly as much of a curve as your Shamshir example. Are there straighter Shamshirs?

Comment: Photo was added by Mark Wallace.  There are many examples of less curved shamshirs on Google images.